# put variables from shell inside ack-grep using alias

Tags: alias, zsh, ack

I want to use ack-grep alias in .zshrc. Here is how my alias lookes like now:

```
alias 'ack'='ack-grep -C -i -G --match'
```

but what I need is to put strings from this:

```
% ack string1 string2
```

inside

```
alias 'ack'='ack-grep -C -i -G string1 --match string2'
```

How to make this?

## **Update**

Here is the code that worked:

```
ack() { 
    case $# in
    1) args="$1";;
    2) args="$1 -G $2";;
    *) args="$@";;
    esac
    eval "ack-grep -iC $args"
}
```

In my case I need to use `eval` for using more than one variable.

## **Update 2**

Updated code without security issues:

```
ack () {
    if (( $# == 2 )); then
        ack-grep -iC "$1" -G "$2"
    elif (( $# == 1 )); then
        ack-grep -iC "$1"
    else
        echo 'Sorry, function works only for one and two params. In other case use ack-grep. Reread .zshrc'
    fi
}
```

Comment: Don't use `eval` unless you absolutely have to. And in this case, you don't.

Comment: Why I should not use `eval` ?

Comment: It can be a security risk unless you have *absolute* control over the variables being expanded inside its argument, and it's making the shell do extra work instead of specifying exactly what you want the shell to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` is rarely necessary.

```sh
ack () { 
    if (( $# > 2 )); then
        ack-grep -iC "$@"
    else
        ack-grep -iC "$1" ${2:+-G "$2"}
    fi
}
```

Update: here is an exact version of your first solution, without `eval`.

```
ack() { 
    case $# in
    1) ack-grep -iC "$1";;
    2) ack-grep -iC "$1" -G "$2";;
    *) ack-grep -iC "$@";;
    esac
}
```

Comment: This function doesn't work because if I use `ack String` it works identical to `ack-grep -iC String`. But if you put `ack String String2` it outputs nothing, in difference to `ack-grep -iC String -G String2`.

Comment: The code you posted in your update is different from the code in your original question and in William Pursell's answer (does `$1` go with `-G` or does it stand alone? Does `$2` go with `-G` or `--match`?)

Comment: Ok. The last version is really useful but it has restrictions. With `eval` I could use any other params if i need. But iif it can be a security issue, i'd use the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use a function:

ack() { ack-grep -C -i -G $1 --match $2; }
```

You will probably want to make it slightly more robust.  Something like:

```
ack() { 
    case $# in
    1) args="-G $1";;
    2) args="-G $1 --match $2";;
    *) args="$@";;
    esac
    ack-grep -C -i "$args"
}
```

Aliases do not provide adequate functionality for this sort of thing, and functions should almost always be used instead.  (In fact, you can omit "almost" from the preceding.)

Comment: Thanks. In my case the variation of your example worked. I've updated the post with it.